# Moment.js guess timezone is temporarily loading incorrect timezone

Tags: webpack, momentjs, webpack-hmr

Moment.js guess timezone is temporarily loading UTC then switching to the correct timezone.

I've narrowed it down to what seems to be that webpack is loading the `bundle.js` file first before `moment.tz.guess()` gets the correct timezone.

[image]

Look at the loading time, and see how the timezone changes after `bundle.js` has completed loading.

Any ideas how to resolve this? Kinda out of it today :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it! :D

So basically since we're using [HMR](https://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement.html) for server and client side rendering, the issue was that it was loading `UTC` on the server, sending it down as `UTC` then being overwritten by the client with the correct timezone.  All I had to do was something like this.

```
const __CLIENT__ = !!global.window

export class Something extends Component {
  state = {
    timezone: /\(([^)]+)\)/.exec(new Date())[1]
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {__CLIENT__ && <div>{`Times are being displayed in ${timezone} time.`}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```